# Arara continue when launching pdf reader in background

Tags: linux, arara

I want to configure `arara` to launch my PDF reader after compilation. I can do this with the following custom rule:

```yml
!config
identifier: evince
name: evince
commands:
- name: Open in Evince
  command: >
    @{
      name = 'build/'+getBasename(reference.getName()) + '.pdf';
      return getCommand(['evince', name])
    }
arguments: []
```

However when using this rule, `arara` just hangs until I close the PDF reader again:

```
(LaTeXmk) Tool LaTeXmk .................................. SUCCESS
(evince) Open in Evince .................................
```

Appending `&` to the command just makes `evince` try to open the file `&amp;`. I tried various combinations of `nohup`, `setsid`, `coproc` and `disown` both directly from this rule, or by indirectly calling `evince` from a bash script, but nothing changes. Arara refuses to continue unless I stop my PDF reader.

Any suggestions on how to make arara continue after spawning the PDF reader as a background process?

Comment: If Evince is your default pdf reader maybe you can use `xdg-open name` instead? I think that returns immediately.

Comment: While this correctly opens the PDF with evince, it still doesn't return.

Comment: Indirectly calling evince from bash script should work as long as you put the `&` inside the bash script itself. What do you write in the bash script exactly?

Comment: I wrote 
`#!/bin/bash` followed by
`evince $1 &`
And I would expect that to work. My only success is when I used 
`coproc evince $1 disown`. This successfully returns, but also makes evince try to open a file called `disown` and give a pop up with an error. (Adding an & before disown does not work). 
The problem is also not with evince; if I replace evince with okular I have the same issue.

Comment: Maybe put an explicit `return 0` at the end of the script? I'm not sure how Arara checks that a command is finished, possibly setting the return value would help.

Comment: This did not work, but it did lead me to a solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In the end I was able to solve it by calling the following bash script (replacing `evince` above by a call to this script):

```
#!/bin/bash
evince $1 > /dev/null &
exit 0
```

What is interesting is that both redirecting output to `/dev/null` *and* returning with `exit 0` are essential. My guess is that this a bug in arara, but I will try to reproduce it on a different machine before reporting it.

Comment: Hello! It's not a bug, this behaviour is by design: `arara` always waits for the process to finish...

Comment: I still think it's a bug. Spawning a background process and exiting with code 0 should allow `arara` to continue. The necessity for output to be redirected to `/dev/null`, and explicitly calling `exit 0` is unexpected. The problem isn't necessarily with `arara`, but I certainly think that this behavior is strange.

Comment: The team is keen on discussing about this, thanks a lot for raising it up. `:)` Just a note: it might be a surprising behaviour, but it's expected, so it's not a bug, as we explicitly wait for process termination. We will see what can be done for future versions. `:)`